# Button click event in c# WPF DataGrid not reliable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have the problem, that a click event of a button in a WPF DataGrid is not always propagated to the event handler.
It is .NET 6 WPF application using C#.
This is the xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MyApp" Height="600" Width="1050">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">

        <Grid Margin="4,4,4,4" x:Name="main" DockPanel.Dock="Top" MinHeight="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" x:Name="Tab"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TabControl Grid.Row="0" >
                <TabItem Header="Setup" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="List">
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <DataGrid Background="#FF55AAEE" x:Name="InstrumentGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding elements}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  AlternatingRowBackground="#333333" AlternationCount="2" IsReadOnly="True"  SelectionMode="Single">
                            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nameame" Width="130" Binding="{Binding name}" SortDirection="Ascending" >
                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                </DataGridTextColumn>                           
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Chart" Width="100">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button Content="Open" Click="ClickEventHandler" CommandParameter="{Binding name}" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>                                
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </DockPanel>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And this is the event handler:

```
namespace MyApp {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        private void ClickEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            // Sometimes called, sometimes not.
        }// ClickEventHandler
    }
}
```

So this event handler is sometimes called, sometimes not.
The Main refreshes the DataGrid in a timer callback,  which is called each 200 MS.

```
namespace MyApp {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {

      private void gui_member_update_timer(object sender, EventArgs e) {
          List.NotifyChanges();
      }
  }
}
```

When i put breakpoint in the event handler, this breakpoint sometimes not triggered,
even button been pushed.

How to make the button click event reliable?

Thank you

This is the Collection the thread safe collection connected to the list:

```
namespace TSCollection {
    public class FastObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> {
        private readonly object locker = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// This private variable holds the flag to
        /// turn on and off the collection changed notification.
        /// </summary>
        private bool suspendCollectionChangeNotification;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the FastObservableCollection class.
        /// </summary>
        public FastObservableCollection()
            : base() {
            this.suspendCollectionChangeNotification = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This event is overriden CollectionChanged event of the observable collection.
        /// </summary>
        public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// This method adds the given generic list of items
        /// as a range into current collection by casting them as type T.
        /// It then notifies once after all items are added.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="items">The source collection.</param>
        public void AddItems(IList<T> items) {
            lock (locker) {
                this.SuspendCollectionChangeNotification();
                foreach (var i in items) {
                    if (i != null)
                        InsertItem(Count, i);
                }
                this.NotifyChanges();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method adds a single item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="items">The source collection.</param>
        public void AddItem(T item) {
            lock (locker) {
                if (item != null) {
                    InsertItem(Count, item);
                    this.NotifyChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises collection change event.
        /// </summary>
        public void NotifyChanges() {
            this.ResumeCollectionChangeNotification();
            var arg
                 = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
                      (NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
            this.OnCollectionChanged(arg);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method removes the given generic list of items as a range
        /// into current collection by casting them as type T.
        /// It then notifies once after all items are removed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="items">The source collection.</param>
        public void RemoveItems(IList<T> items) {
            lock (locker) {
                this.SuspendCollectionChangeNotification();
                foreach (var i in items) {
                    Remove(i);
                }
                this.NotifyChanges();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method removes a single item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="items">The source collection.</param>
        public void RemoveItem(T item) {
            lock (locker) {
                this.SuspendCollectionChangeNotification();
                Remove(item);
                this.NotifyChanges();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Resumes collection changed notification.
        /// </summary>
        public void ResumeCollectionChangeNotification() {
            this.suspendCollectionChangeNotification = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Suspends collection changed notification.
        /// </summary>
        public void SuspendCollectionChangeNotification() {
            this.suspendCollectionChangeNotification = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This collection changed event performs thread safe event raising.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">The event argument.</param>
        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            // Recommended is to avoid reentry 
            // in collection changed event while collection
            // is getting changed on other thread.
            using (BlockReentrancy()) {
                if (!this.suspendCollectionChangeNotification) {
                    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler eventHandler =
                          this.CollectionChanged;
                    if (eventHandler == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Walk thru invocation list.
                    System.Delegate[] delegates = eventHandler.GetInvocationList();

                    foreach
                    (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler in delegates) {
                        // If the subscriber is a DispatcherObject and different thread.
                        DispatcherObject dispatcherObject
                             = handler.Target as DispatcherObject;

                        if (dispatcherObject != null
                               && !dispatcherObject.CheckAccess()) {
                            // Invoke handler in the target dispatcher's thread... 
                            // asynchronously for better responsiveness.
                            dispatcherObject.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
                                  (DispatcherPriority.DataBind, handler, this, e);
                        }
                        else {
                            // Execute handler as is.
                            handler(this, e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view model that has an instance of the collection.
Just showing most important:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
         if (PropertyChanged != null) {
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
         }
     }
 }

 internal partial class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel {
     private FastObservableCollection<InstrumentWrapperVisual>? _elements;
     //...
      public FastObservableCollection<VisualElement>? elements {
          get { return _elements; }
      }

     
}
```

The VisualElement has properties according column names of DataGrid.
When i add a VisualElement and call elements.NotifyChanged, a row representing this VisualElement is added. So far so good.

When i change a value of such a VisualElement in elements, nothing happens until i call elements.NotifyChanged.

Comment: Refreshing the datagrid 5 times a second seems a bit extreme, especially if the datagrid source collection is large. Can you provide code on how you're performing this update to your collection?

Comment: I do this refreshing because simple change of data does not reflect the change in the grid. When calling NotifyChange,  the grid is updated.

Comment: Hello, have extended the code with collection class and View Model.

Comment: I agree with @bigcrazyal that the refresh rate seems way too excessive for a WIndows Application, and that this is probably the cause of the issue - that the button click happens at the same time the datagrid is being refreshed. Have you tried setting the refresh rate to 3 seconds and check if the issue occurs less often?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Lower refesh rate brings mitigation and buton click more likely recognize. But, how to update DataGrid then? When i change the values of the models, those values are not updated until NotifyChanged called. Lets have a DataGrid with 1000 rows and 10 columns showing stock data,  there are much more changes just than 5 times per second. How to use DataGrid that is able to update 1000 rows x 10 columns? Thank you for any idea.